# Multiple custom blocks on custom module

Tags: blocks

I would like to know if it's possible and if so is it a good idea to create a custom module and then create more than one custom blocks for it. Would this be a good approach or should I create a new module for every custom block I want to create.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Magento, you can have multiple blocks in same module. No need to create separate module for each block.